# Ruby and Timeout.timeout performance issue

Tags: ruby, performance, sinatra, performance-testing

I'm not sure how to solve this big performance issue of my application. I'm using open-uri to request the most popular videos from youtube and when I ran perftools https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb

It shows that the biggest performance issue is Timeout.timeout. Can anyone suggest me how to solve the problem?

I'm using ruby 1.8.7.

**Edit:**

This is the output from my profiler

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B4bANr--YcONZDRlMmFhZjQtYzIyOS00YjZjLWFlMGUtMTQyNzU5ZmYzZTU4&hl=en_US

Comment: Please show the actual profiling output, don't just tell us about it, so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: It's blamed on Timeout but the code within the block is probably waiting on a response from the remote server. I agree that the output needs to be added for better understanding.

Comment: I've uploaded my output to google docs https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B4bANr--YcONZDRlMmFhZjQtYzIyOS00YjZjLWFlMGUtMTQyNzU5ZmYzZTU4&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeout is wrapping the function that is actually doing the work to ensure that if the server fails to respond within a certain time, the code will raise an error and stop execution.

I suspect that what you are seeing is that the server is taking some time to respond. You should look at caching the response in some way.

For instance, using [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (pseudocode)

```
require 'dalli'
require 'open-uri'

DALLI = Dalli.client.new

class PopularVideos
  def self.get
    result = []
    unless result = DALLI.get("videos_#{Date.today.to_s}")
      doc = open("http://youtube/url")
      result = parse_videos(doc) # parse the doc somehow
      DALLI.set("videos_#{Date.today.to_s}", result)
    end
    result
  end
end

PopularVideos.get # calls your expensive parsing script once
PopularVideos.get # gets the result from memcached for the rest of the day
```

Comment: Also, I notice you're using Sinatra. With Padrino (extends Sinatra) you get some useful caching extensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Anything else I should change.:-)